# how to subtract two dates and show as hours and minutes in text box in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've two date variables and want to return time in HH:mm format to text box using jquery. 
I have two textboxes for date future and date now. I'm getting their values by:

```
var date_now = $('#date_now').val();
var date_future = $('#date_future).val();
```

how to convert the delta to date difference to fit this code.

```
var delta = Math.abs(date_future - date_now) / 1000;

var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
delta -= days * 86400;

var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
delta -= hours * 3600;

var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
delta -= minutes * 60;

var seconds = delta % 60;
```

I want to get above variables of days hour minutes to textbox in format hh:mm.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Date`

```
d=new Date();
hr=d.getHours();
min=d.getMinutes();
```

also to get in a string format you could use:

```
var d1 = new Date(dateString);
var d2 = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
d.toLocaleTimeString() // "11:24:57 PM"
//and can get parts using...
d.toLocaleTimeString('en', { minute:"numeric" });//gives numeric number of minutes
```

you can also use `d.toTimeString()` to get a string representation as well. 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

---

you could also do

```
var str1 = "34:22";
var times1 = str1.split(":");
var str2 = "34:22";
var times2 = str2.split(":");
var deltaMin = parseInt(times1[1]) - parseInt(times2[1])
var deltaHour = parseInt(times1[0]) - parseInt(times2[0])
if(deltaMin<0){
    --deltaHour;
    deltaMin = 60 + deltaMin;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But is there any convention by which I still get hh:mm if hours go beyond 24. For eg. 26:44 depicting 26 hours 44 minutes